# Flipping a coin probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

Flipping a coin

The first two flips Has a 24.5% chance Each Landing on heads

The second two flips has a 32.9% Chance Each landing on heads

The fifth flip has a 35% Chance landing on heads

What is the chance of the coin landing on heads 3 out of 5 times

Comment: Please read this before you post your next question. [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: I don't see how we can answer that without knowing the probabilities for the fourth and fifth  flips

Comment: I assume the last line should read "the fifth" flip.  Also, do you mean exactly three out of five or at least three out of five?   But, what have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Ok sorry mb changed the question

Comment: I have to use binomial distribution or something I learned in high school I forgot someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Say you get the first three coins. That's a $24.5\% \cdot 24.5\% \cdot 32.9\%\cdot 67.1\% \cdot 65\%.$ (The last two are the probability of getting *tails* instead of *heads*.)

Similarly, say you get 1, 2, 4th coints. That's the same probability. And so on. 1, 2, 5th coins, 1, 3, 4th coins, 1, 3, 5th coins....

You should be able to do this. At the end, you should get $$2\cdot24.5\%^2\cdot 32.9\%\cdot 67.1\% \cdot 65\% + 4\cdot 24.5\% \cdot 32.9\% \cdot 35\% \cdot 75.5\% \cdot 67.1\% + 2\cdot 24.5\% \cdot 32.9\%^2 \cdot 75.5\% \cdot 65\% + 24.5\%^2 \cdot 35\% \cdot 67.1\%^2 + 32.9\%^2 \cdot 35\% \cdot 75.5\%.$$

That's a lot!

Calculating this gets the answer of $0.05954$, or a $$5.95\% \text{ chance.}$$

Comment: Hey just wanna ask if I have to use binomial distribution on this question